# nagios/icinga flapping notifications not sent?

Tags: nagios, icinga

I've seen this on nagios and on my current icinga installation.

I have flap detection turned on. I have my contact definition set to:

> ```
>    service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f
>    host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
> ```

When a service starts flapping, the web interface says notifications are being suppressed due to flapping. I don't get a notification that says the service is flapping.

But I want that notification - because otherwise I'm not getting any notification at all that something is up with the relevant host/service.

Am I misconfiguring things?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add `f` to the `service_notification_options`.

The set of emails that a contact actually receives is the intersection of the service's (or host's) options and the contact's options.